# Trying to use same letter for hotkey using alt and alt+shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am using Chrome and trying to use JQuery to map **alt+a** to one input and **alt+shift+a** to the other input. I have debugged through it using chrome and still can't figure it out. I am confused as the best way to do this. I am not sure if this is possible. I also tried using accesskey="a" on both inputs but in that case it just hits the second input.

Any ideas or help will be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
         $(document).ready( function () {
         $(document).keyup('alt+a',       function () { $('suc').click(); });
         $(document).keyup('alt+shift+a', function () { $('try').click(); } );
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <input type="submit" formaction="file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/success.html" value="Success" accesskey="a" id="suc">
         <input type="submit" formaction="file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/tryAgain.html" value="TryAgain" accesskey="a" id="try" >
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I am going to try them now :)

Comment: Turned out I set the accesskey attribute and was trying to set hotkeys using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I set the accesskey attribute and was trying to set hotkeys using jquery.

Chrome sounds like an error has occurred. I used this article for help: http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188026/Easy-Keyboard-Shortcuts-for-Web-Pages

and am going to move forward with https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).keyup(
            function(e) {
                e = e || window.event; // because of Internet Explorer quirks...
                k = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode; // because of browser differences...
                if (k == 65 && e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
                    $('form').prop('action', 'file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/tryAgain.html').submit();
                } else if (k == 65 && e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {
                    $('form').prop('action', 'file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/success.html').submit();
                } else {
                    return true; // it's not a key we recognize, move on...
                }
                return false;
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="submit" formaction="file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/success.html" value="Success" id="suc">
<input type="submit" formaction="file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/tryAgain.html" value="TryAgain" id="try" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty to handle keyboard events.

It would look something like so

```
jwerty.key('alt+a', function() {
    // success
});

jwerty.key('alt+shift+a', function() {
    // try again
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, alt+shift+a doesn't seem to be responding as expected in Chrome, maybe there's a conflict.  I'm getting both alt+a and alt+shift+a triggering #try with the following code:

```
$(window).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.altKey && e.which===97)
        $('#suc').trigger('submit');
});
$(window).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.which===97)
        $('#try').trigger('submit');
});
```

You might try `if(e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.which===97)` on #try instead.

Comment: Thank you Nolo, yeah I checked chromes reserved keys and Alt+Shift+a isn't reserved?